# Add double quotations in List to send API request in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to add double quotation in list of each string item so that I can make a JSON request to send to api.
var response = default(HttpResponseMessage);
using var httpClient = CreateHttpClientForRequest();

```
        var kpis = string.Join<string>(",", (IEnumerable<string>)keyProcessInstance);
       
        using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, PathfinderDeleteActiveUri)
        {             
            Content = new StringContent ($@"[""{kpis}""]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")            
        };
```

I need this type of format in kpis variable.
["string1","string2","string"]

but not able to add "" for each string in the kpis.

Comment: You don't need to quote anything to generate a JSON array. Serialize the array directly, eg: `json=JsonSerializer.Serialize(keyProcessInstance);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` to serialize your list to JSON.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

...

string kpis = JsonSerializer.Serialize(keyProcessInstance);
       
using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, PathfinderDeleteActiveUri)
{             
    Content = new StringContent(kpis, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")            
};
```

**For educational purposes only**, this is what you could do to make it work with your own approach.

```cs
var kpis = string.Join<string>("\",\"", (IEnumerable<string>)keyProcessInstance);
       
using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, PathfinderDeleteActiveUri)
{             
    Content = new StringContent($"[\"{kpis}\"]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")            
};
```

You have to use backslash to use quotes in a string `\"`.

Comment: Thankyou so much . But now after adding these lines,                                                   
 var kpis = string.Join<string>("\",\"", (IEnumerable<string>)keyProcessInstance);
       
using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, PathfinderDeleteActiveUri)
{             
    Content = new StringContent($"[\"{kpis}\"]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")            
};     

But now my output is coming like this:
"[\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\"]"

I need to remove "" only. So that my output will become like this 
[string1","string2","string3"]

Comment: @MaheenAli you don't need to remove anything. `\"` is how the debugger displays quotes inside strings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos totally got your point I dont want to remove \ i need to remove double quotation before the brackts[] . so that my output will become like this: [\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\"] .

Comment: You don't need to remove anything. You mistake the debugger's view for the actual content. The debugger displays strings the same way you'd write them in C# - strings are surrounded by double quotes. Which means any special characters need to be escaped

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.Many thanks to you it worked now  perfectly. Stay blessed. Just one thing, can you please suggest me any tutorials through which I can learn this thing for my own knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to quote array values, the JSON serializer will do it automatically. In .NET 5 and later you can use [JsonContent.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent.create?view=net-6.0) to create a JsonContent object that serializes its payload automatically:

```
var jsonContent=JsonContent.Create(keyProcessInstance);
using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, uri)
        {             
            Content = jsonContent           
        };
await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

The [default media type](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/95c7952be3f672191766dcffca64196a51cfb5bd/src/libraries/System.Net.Http.Json/src/System/Net/Http/Json/JsonHelpers.cs#L15) for JsonContent is `application/json` with CharSet `utf-8`